# Sort posts by meta key that is serialised with other meta keys

Tags: sort

I need price sorting, where price is a metakey that is serialisez with other metakeys and stored in wp_postmeta

### I need something like this:

When user click on **free** (Anchor tag) it should show posts with price '0'

When they click on **paid** (Anchor tag) it should show posts with price excluding '0'

Serialised Meta value 
    a:7:{s:19:"et_is_editor_choice";s:1:"0";s:15:"et_fs_variation";s:1:"0";s:12:"et_fs_button";s:0:"";s:10:"et_fs_link";s:0:"";s:11:"et_fs_price";s:0:"";s:17:"et_affiliate_link";s:0:"";s:17:"et_affiliate_text";s:0:"";}

Comment: you will find it prohibitively difficult to query on PHP serialized data, as it is essentially nonsense as far as MySQL is concerned. you should store price separately under its own key if you want to query on that data.

Comment: @Milo - can you post this as an answer? - it is after all, the correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

You will find it prohibitively difficult to query on PHP serialized data, as it is essentially nonsense as far as MySQL is concerned. You should store price separately under its own key if you want to query on that data.

Comment: I thought about that but, i have more than 5000 posts.
Is there any other way.

Comment: @dayakarreddy - the only way I know of is to select every post, unserialize every meta value, then compare them all with php, which is obviously not a realistic solution.